# How should I make a divider that doesn't necessarily represent a thematic break <hr> vs <span>,<div>,css etc

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

I've always liked the `<hr>` tag as a design divider because it's a concise empty tag and you can use CSS to design it with a theme.  I like it better than border-bottom because you can set the width to be smaller than the content above it i.e. 25% of the container width.

I almost feel like there should be an empty tag that serves as an anchor point for css design.

I know I can do this with any tag with CSS:
`<div class=divider></div>`

works just fine but it's not as concise as `<hr>`

So to me `<hr>` seems like the best choice on the surface.

Then I read the HTML5 semantic meaning of `<hr>` which says it is a thematic break.  (That seems a little arbitrary) is a title a different theme than it's content?  What about semantic cases where I want to have a featured title for a post with a nice box over an image with the title on top and a divider and the sub-title under it?

I want my content to make sense for syndication and I want it to look good if it's opened in an alternate css liked reader on safari which again seems to say `<hr>` isn't a good choice.

Should I use `<span class=divider></span>` that seems wasteful.
I have also considered `<svg>` or `<br>` but to me `<br>` seems like an empty line and possible also semantically like a pause like a comma in a sentence.
What's the best way to have a horizontal divider semantically when the primary reason is design preference and not a thematic break?

Comment: I'd suggest, if the purpose is to visually separate a heading element from the content you could simply use the `::after`, or `::before`, pseudo elements which makes the separator - however it's styled - a part of the header itself, or the following content (depending on which element you place the pseudo-element on).

Comment: There probably is a way to do it with those pseudo elements that I can't think of.  I know there is a way to do it with pseudo elements if I want the line to be the same width as the parent.  This css on hr makes a really nice break line but it doesn't work with those pseudo elements    `border: 0.1em solid #3cc19c;
    margin: 0 42% 1.5em;`

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you want, but in principle it's easy enough: [jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L27etwsv/](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L27etwsv/).

Comment: You can do the same as you do with the `hr` maybe on some cases need extra properties but is the same behavior http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJgZPy

Comment: I like the ::after pseudo approach I thought the after class was bound to it's parent's width and apparently not

Comment: Is there a way to have the ::after class's width relative to it's real element?  I may not always want a fixed width bar in a smaller frame or something.

Comment: I came up with this and I still feel like it's inelegant `h2::after {
    transform: scale(6,.5);
    content: "―";
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - -3px);
    margin-top: 1em;
}`

Comment: The width always be relative to the parent container if you set it to block .... And what is that code you post ? scale - calc - content ? Please make a codepen or jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think out of your suggestions I would just go ahead and use the separate custom div `<div class="box-divider"></div>` it's really not that wasteful if it's an integral part of your structure and gives you the max flexibility in terms of what your divider will look like and positioning. You can honestly do the same to an `<hr>` tag if you customize it's css you can make it look however you want.

A lot of users have commented about using psuedo elements on the element that needs a divider which is a fine suggestion.

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}

.box:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

If it's as simple as a border line you can just use `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` for example to the element itself and forgo the need for a separate element all together. Add some padding-bottom to control the positioning.

All in all if it's a tricky/custom divider that you need I would just go for the separate div divider or pseudo elements.

Comment: Yeah that's probably going to be the best answer.  I kind of would like to see them add a new empty tag in HTML6 to act as an anchor point for css